# npm ERR! code E401 Incorrect or missing password.If you were trying to login, change your password, create an authentication token

Tags: npm, lerna, npm-registry, npm-config, npm-login

Before Trying tis on My new M1 Macbook Air i tried it on Old MacBook and it works seamlessly on older machine like a charm
My

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.20.2"
  }
}
```

Steps i followed

1.

> npm config set registry "https://npm.pkg.github.com/ABC"

2. 

> npm login --scope=@ABC --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
>
> username: gitusername
>
> Password: PersonalAccessToken
>
> Email: MyEmail@Organization.com
>
> Logged in as gitusername on https://npm.pkg.github.com/.

3.

> npm install -g lerna typescript npm-check-updates

Facing this issue as

```
npm ERR! code E401 
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password. 
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an 
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then 
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly. 
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at: npm ERR!     
                   https://www.npmjs.com/forgot 
npm ERR! npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with: 
npm ERR! npm login
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR! /Users/gajanan/.npm/_logs/2021-04-02T05_22_22_130Z-debug.log
```

PS :ALL THE COMMANDS WORKS ON MY OLD MACBOOK AIR

I struggle with this problem for a very long time, read all the related answers, but there is no clarity.

Comment: Solved the issue by deleting .npmrc file from your
Users/YourSystemName. 
and reinstalling all the installation like 
npm install -g lerna typescript npm-check-updates 
It works

Comment: what is location of this file.@Gajanan

Comment: @GajananShinde this worked for me, no idea why. I'm sending you my grateful energy now.